# MDX Measure Filtering

Tags: mdx, pentaho, mondrian

I am building a Mondrian Cube that shows information for a large range of dates.  One of the measures for this cube is an average of a percentage value.  Because some of the items in the cube should not make up the final average, I need to know how to filter them out based off this measure and only for this calculated member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution to this thanks to the group over at the Pentaho forum:

http://forums.pentaho.org/showthread.php?t=75742